# How to make a document with continuous text on odd pages only in latex?

Tags: latex

Heey all,

For my thesis, I'm dealing with a lot of figures with experimental data in one chapter. To maintain an overview for the reader, I would like to have text on the odd pages and figures on even pages. This way, when printing the document all text would be printed on the right side of the opened booklet and the figures on the left.

Anyone an idea how to create this in latex?